# Не работает редирект HttpResponseRedirect django

Tags: python, django

Редирект идет на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/edit/orders_home`, а должен на `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/`

**views.py**

```
class OrderEditView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_edit.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_order = Orders.objects.get(pk=context['order_id'])        
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(instance=get_order)
        formOne.prefix = 'one_form'
        context.update({'formOne': formOne})
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')
       
        get_order = Orders.objects.get(pk=context['order_id'])
        
        if formOne.is_valid():
            formOne.save()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formOne, form_list, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formOne.prefix = 'one_form'        
        context.update({'formOne': formOne})
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', OrdersHomeView.as_view(), name='orders_home'),
    path('edit/<int:order_id>', OrderEditView.as_view(), name='order_edit'),
]
```

Comment: как вариант так return `HttpResponseRedirect('/orders_home')`

Comment: или так `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('orders_home'))`

Comment: Код у вас полностью рабочий, вот только ваш OrderEditView не отдаёт нужную страницу.

Comment: помогло httpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('orders_home'))